# React Router: Pass Props to Nested, Dynamic Pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

#### Rendering `Result` components using `map` and passing props.

```js
<div className="results">
  {data.map((movie) => (
    <Result
      poster={movie.poster_path}
      alt={movie.title}
      key={movie.id}
      id={movie.id}
    />
  ))}
</div>
```

#### My `Result` component that receives props

```js
export default function Result(props) {
  const { poster, alt, id } = props;

  return (
    <div className="result">
      <Link to={`/results/${id}`}>
        <img
          src={
            poster
              ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${poster}`
              : "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg"
          }
          alt={alt}
        />
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### I have my dynamic routes.

```js
<Route path={"/results/:id"}>
   <ResultPage />
</Route>
```

#### I have my dynamic `ResultPage`, but I don't know how to pass the `Result` component's props to this page.

```js
export default function ResultPage(props) {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div className="resultPage">
      <h3>this is page: {id}</h3>
      {/* I WANT TO PASS & DISPLAY PROPS HERE */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### `Result.jsx`

```
export default function Result(props) {
  const { poster, alt, id } = props;
  const history = useHistory();
  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push({
      pathname: `/results/${id}`,
      state: {
         poster,
         alt
       }
    })
  }
  return (
    <div className="result">
        <img
          onClick ={handleClick}
          src={
            poster
              ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${poster}`
              : "https://www.genius100visions.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/placeholder-vertical.jpg"
          }
          alt={alt}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### `ResultPage.jsx`

```
export default function ResultPage(props) {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <div className="resultPage">
      <h3>this is page: {id}</h3>
      <p> {location.state.poster} </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Instead of `Link` component I have added an `onClick` event handler to the `img` tag and then in the `handleClick` method I'm `useHistory.push()` to send `props` from the Result Component to `ResultPage` component.

The `location` object has a `state` property, which now contains the `props` passed through the `Result` Component.

Comment: hmmm, i tried this, but it's still not rendering

Comment: can you log and  check the location object, does it contains the state property?

Comment: yep, if i log {location.state} it renders the movie.title of the item i clicked on. but if i log {location} i don’t see the other props (alt & poster). any thoughts?

Comment: I have updated the code.. explicitly assigned the props value to state.

Comment: Check this post of mine on passing values in history.push with a working example. https://surajsharma.net/blog/react-router-dom-pass-data